# PHP explode function only allows me to detect first item of array when i search in_array. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode, implode

I've converted checkbox data into a string to store in my database.

However, when I try to convert the string back into an array with the explode function, I am having trouble searching in_array for anything apart from the first item. Why?

```
$rolepref = explode(',', $roles);
print_r($rolepref) = [0] Strategy [1] Operations
if (in_array("Strategy", $rolepref) { echo "yes" } => Will echo yes
if (in_array("Operations", $rolepref) { echo "yes" } => Does not work
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the actual array you're trying to check? and the actual code. Looks like you've just typed this up as it's not complete (missing closing brackets on if statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have white spaces after explode data. Try to explode with trim

```
$roles = "Strategy, Operations";
$rolepref = array_map('trim', explode(',', $roles)); //trim and explode data
if (in_array("Strategy", $rolepref)) { echo "yes"; }
if (in_array("Operations", $rolepref)) { echo "yes"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have your `$roles` as: `"Strategy, Operations"` and when you `explode` it using a `,` it would give you two elements: `"Strategy"` and `" Operations"`... Notice the extra space before the word *Operations*. So trim the space before comparing each element.

`$roles = "Strategy, Operations"; // lets say
$rolepref = array_map('trim', explode(',', $roles));
if (in_array("Strategy", $rolepref)) { echo "yes"; }
if (in_array("Operations", $rolepref)) { echo "yes"; }`

Answer (score 0):

in_array returns true if it finds an **EXACT** value.
It's possible your array is not exactly the same, try cleaning it with trim()

The below code works.

```
$array = [
    0 => 'Strategy',
    1 => 'Operations',
];

if (in_array("Strategy", $array))
{
    echo "yes s <br />";
}

if (in_array("Operations", $array))
{
    echo "yes o <br />";
}
```